# Differences between A1 fixed referencing and formulaR1C1 relative positioning VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that populates cells on a blank worksheet with values from another form worksheet using `R1C1`. The issue is that the position of the source data on the form worksheet changes as users add rows to input their data. The `A1` solution to this would be to use a fix Cell column reference and allow the reference for the row to change `9ex`. `Cell=Sheet1!$A25`, which could then change to `Cell=Sheet1!$A26` as a row is added above. How can I make my `FormulaR1C1` change in the same way as my `A1`?

Correct situation:

```
Cell A1=Sheet1!$F13
```

Therefore, `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[12]C6"`

But when I add a row above F13:

```
Cell A1=Sheet1!$F14
```

But, `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[12]C6"`, Does not respond to the shift row down

Comment: Correct. R1C1 method states the position *relative to that cell's own position*, instead of in absolute terms. That means the formula looks identical regardless of what cell it's in - because instead of changing what the *reference* looks like, it changes the fact that the reference is now *relative* to the new cell.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon Hey thanks, Could you suggest a alternative to get the solution I want?

Comment: What I mean is - even though the *visible formula* didn't change, everything shifted down and referred to the new row down below anyway. It's still [12] rows below the cell the formula is in. ie: A1+12 = F13. A2+12 = F14. Another way to write those to formulas, instead of saying "A1" & "A2" would be to say "Current Cell". ie: Current Cell + 12 = F13 when the formula is in A1, and F14 when the formula is in A2.